# url get wont work on google chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Hi i have a problem with google chrome GET section. You can understand better with this **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/imposiblepassion/pen/MXzxeJ)**

Please open the demo page using google chrome and internet explorer or firefox. It is working fine internet explorer, firefox or other browsers but not working on chrome only.

Anyone can help me here please.

The code.php file codes is here:

```
<?php if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start(); header( "(anti-spam-content-type:) image/png" );

$acf_num = rand( 0, 9999 );
$code_num = rand( 0, 24 );
$mixed_string = substr( md5( $acf_num ), $code_num, 5 ); // Length of String
$mixed_md5 = md5( $mixed_string );

$_SESSION['SocialMaterial']['AnimationContactForm']['verifyCode'] = $mixed_md5;

// Verification Image Background randomizer
$rand = dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/';
$CoDes = array(
    $rand . 'acf_img/verify/1.png',
    $rand . 'acf_img/verify/2.png',
    $rand . 'acf_img/verify/3.png'
);
$VerifyCodes = array_rand( $CoDes, 1 );

// Verification Image Configurations
$img_handle = imagecreatefrompng( $CoDes[$VerifyCodes] );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $img_handle, 255, 255, 255 );
$font_size = 50;

$size_array = getimagesize( $CoDes[$VerifyCodes] );
$img_w = $size_array[0];
$img_h = $size_array[1];

$horiz = round( ( $img_w/2 )-( ( strlen( $mixed_string )*imagefontwidth( 50 ) )/2 ), 1 );
$vert = round( ( $img_h/2 )-( imagefontheight( $font_size )/2 ) );

// Make the Verification Image
imagestring( $img_handle, $font_size, $horiz, $vert, $mixed_string, $text_colour );
imagepng( $img_handle );

// Destroy the Image to keep Server Space
imagedestroy( $img_handle );
```

Problem Developer console is this:

[enter image description here](https://image.prntscr.com/image/ktRsHXUGThSNtIoybEQK5w.png)

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker running in Chrome?

Comment: @MrGlass I understood what you saying but i am getting same error also on mobile. I am not using ad blocker on my phone

Comment: Can you try it in Chrome with your ad blocker disabled? Or, it may be `DNT` is enabled in your browser and the server code is honoring it.

Comment: @MrGlass I have tested with disabled ad blocker on chrome and same problem continue. If server code is honoring then it will give me same problem also other browsers.

Comment: Testing the URL in Chrome gives me this error: `ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. That is where your problem lies.

Comment: @MrGlass What is this problem Dear.

Comment: Paste your URL (`https://www.taksiyagmur.com/acf_phpAJAX/code.php`) into a Chrome browser and you will get that error. I see the  same error in the javascript console as well when trying your code on `codepen.io` when using Chrome

Comment: @MrGlass Did you try it another browser ?

Comment: Yes I did. And I pointed out to you that the reason **Chrome** is not working is it generates an error: `ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. If you do not want to look into that error **you will not solve your problem with Chrome**.  Why don't you just try putting your own URL into Chrome and see for yourself??

Comment: You should turn off SPDY support in your web server. It was only ever a non-standard half-measure for HTTP/2 and many services are deprecating and/or removing it now that HTTP/2 is actually a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot verify whether this will solve your problem, but you need to tell the browser what type of image it is with HTML headers like so:

```
  header('Content-type: image/png');
  header('Content-transfer-encoding: binary');
  header('Content-length: '.$size);
```

this is for a PNG file of size `$size`. Headers should be sent to the browser before anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me what is the $size ?

Comment: You can leave the 'Content-length' header out. The `$size` represents the file size of the image, or the number of bytes you will send. An easy way to get it is to buffer the output and check the size of the buffer.

Comment: i have tested your answer and i am getting sema problem.

Comment: You can check it also from the demo. It is working firefox but not working on chrome

Comment: Yes, I have seen the demo. I agree it is weird. However, the headers should be there.

Comment: The next step would be to cut down the code to something simple so others can reproduce your problem. Currently your code cannot be tested. I am almost certain the problem will disappear when you try that, telling you that the problem is not in the rendering of the image itself, but a bug somewhere else.

Comment: Yes you are right bug is somewhere else , but why it will happen just in chrome.